# How to load an property of a class from a service in Typescript/Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I load an object in Typescript from my service?

I have a service that returns a "MyDetail" Object.

The goal is for me to populate a MyDetails Object.

I am getting an error: Property '' is missing in type BehaviorSubject

MyDetails

```
export class MyDetails  {
  myDetail: IMyDetail;
  details: Array<{ dataItems: IDataItem }>;
};
```

Typescript:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  myDetails: MyDetails;
  myDetail: MyDetail;
  private myDetailSubject = new BehaviorSubject<MyDetail>(this.myDetail);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private myDetailService: MyDetailService) {
    route.params.subscribe(x => this.id = x['id'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDetailService.getData(this.id)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.myDetailSubject.next(x);
        this.myDetails.myDetail = this.myDetailSubject;
      });
  }

}
```

EDIT:

MyDetail:

```
export class MyDetail {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   date: Date;
   gizmos: Array<{ gizmo: string }>;
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the `BehaviorSubject` Class?

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: This line looks incorrect: `this.myDetails.myDetail = this.myDetailSubject;`. Did you mean `this.myDetails.myDetail = x;`?

Comment: Yes that was it ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in this line

```
   this.myDetails.myDetail = this.myDetailSubject;
```

which you are assigning `BehaviorSubject<MyDetail>` to `IMyDetail`

so you need to change it, since I don't know what your service is retruning I can't tell you if you should assign `x` or some property of `x` to it.

Btw your code seems to have needless complexity, I think you can remove `myDetailSubject` in your component and using the result of service with `async` pipe or assign it to your private member and let angular binding change your ui

for exapmple

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  myDetails: MyDetails;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private myDetailService: MyDetailService) {
    route.params.subscribe(x => this.id = x['id'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDetailService.getData(this.id)
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.myDetails = x; // or x based on what is return from your service
      });
  }

}

<pre>
  {{myDetails.myDetail | json}}
</pre>
```

or

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  myDetailSubject$ : SubjectBahvior<MyDetail>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, myDetailService: MyDetailService) {
    route.params.subscribe(x => this.id = x['id'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDetailSubject$ = this.myDetailService.getData(this.id);
  }

}

<pre>
  {{myDetailSubject$ | async}}
</pre>
```

Comment: How could I clean it up? (Still new to this)